# how to calculate all nearest neighbours from a byte in a hamming ball

Tags: java, nearest-neighbor, hamming-distance

I want to calculate all possbie hamming neighbours from a given byte with a maximum hamming distance.

For a hamming distance of 1 I have created this function:

```
public static ArrayList<Byte> hammingNeighbours(byte input, int maxDistance){
    ArrayList<Byte> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();
    neighbours.add(input);
    byte value;;
    byte mask = 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            value = (byte) (input ^mask);
            neighbours.add(value);
            mask = (byte) (mask << 1);

        }
    return neighbours;
}
```

But how to add neighbours with a distance > 1?
can someone help me to solve this problem?

best regards

Comment: you want the hamming distance > 1 between what and what?

Comment: No, I want a list of possible neighbors. I give a hamming distance as input and want to calculate all possible neighbors in this hamming radius

Comment: As known input, I have the maximum distance and a string of 8 bits

Comment: Wouldn't it be simply all the other bytes, which are not distance==1 or the input itself?

Comment: oh yes... I can calculate this recursive...thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, all the `byte` which do not have a distance == 1 or 0 would be valid. But if you want an algorithm which will give you all the bytes which are at most `maxDist` away, you could do a recursive method as such:

```
public static void getNeighbours(ArrayList<Byte> nbrs, byte input, int bit, int maxDist) {
    if(maxDist == 0 || bit == 8) {
        nbrs.add(input);
    } else {
        getNeighbours(nbrs, (byte) (input^(1<<bit)), bit+1, maxDist-1);
        getNeighbours(nbrs, input, bit+1, maxDist);
    }
}
```

If you only want the bytes which are exactly `maxDist` away, then only add `if(maxDist == 0)` and terminate the branch `if(bit == 8)`

Answer (score 0):

okay, after simple consideration, I can use my code from the first post and expanse it with a simple recursion to calculate all neighbours:

```
public static HashSet<Byte> hammingNeighbours(byte input, int maxDistance){
    HashSet<Byte> neighbours = new HashSet<>();
    neighbours.add(input);
    byte value;;
    byte mask = 1;


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            value = (byte) (input ^mask);
            if(maxDistance > 1){
            neighbours.addAll(hammingNeighbours(value,maxDistance -1));
            }
            else{
                neighbours.add(value);
            }
            mask = (byte) (mask << 1);

        }
    return neighbours;
}
```

you ca test it with this example code:

```
 HashSet<Byte> bset = hammingNeighbours((byte) 0, 2);
    System.out.println(bset.size());
    for (Byte b : bset) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));;
    }
```